# How do you update an existing item in an Angular Array (that has changed externally)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am new to Angular and am struggling with updating an existing item in my Angular array that has changed externally (not via Angular powered UI).

Here is the use case...My web page is populated via a server side call and I am loading the array into Angular and displaying on a list.

Now, if the data on the server changes and a new record is inserted in the table, my page's JavaScript is notified and it successfully inserts a new records into the Angular array via 'push' (Ref. [Programmatically inserting array values in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860072/programmatically-inserting-array-values-in-angular-js)).

However, my page is also notified when an existing record is changed (on the server side / not via Angular powered UI). I am drawing a blank about how do I go about updating the correct record in my Angular array? Is there a query / update method that I have missed in the Angular docs?

Here is what my current code looks like...

```
    //The HTML UI updates to reflect the new data inserts.
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">        
        <p class="priority">{{item.priority_summary}}</p>
        <p class="type">{{item.type}}</p>
    </div>
```

Here is the Script...

```
    var app = angular.module('DemoApp', []);

    <!-- Define controller -->
    var contrl = app.controller("MainController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
        "status": "New",
            "priority_summary": "High"
    }, {
        "status": "New",
            "priority_summary": "High"
    }, {
        "status": "New",
            "priority_summary": "High"
    }, {
        "status": "New",
            "priority_summary": "High"
    }];

//The insert works fine. The question is how do I do an update if the notification is for an update, and not for insert.

    $scope.addItem = function(item)
    {
     alert("addItem called");
     $scope.items.push(item);
     $scope.item = {};
    }

      $scope.subscribe = function(){
        //Code for connecting to the endpoint...
        alert("event received"); //We receive this alert, so event is received correctly.

        $scope.items.push({
          status: 'New',
          priority_summary: 'H'
        });
        $scope.$apply();

        }

      //calling subscribe on controller initialization...
      $scope.subscribe();
```

Any suggestions or examples highlighting this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What is that you are looking for ?
You are already receiving notification for change plus you are able to push updated data ?

Comment: @hasH: I am able to insert new items, but I am not sure how do I update existing items in the array. The typical Angular filter seem to be geared towards UI, while I am trying to make the change in the array's item itself. Does that make sense?

Comment: can you get the index of data you need to update ?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. I do have a unique Id for every record in the JSON that I am receiving. Do I just search through the array as one normally does, or is there an Angular method which makes it easy?

Comment: I think so you need the just replace the updated data with the correct data in the array...also as of i know this has to be done by you itself as there is nothing as of query/update ...yes it can be done using the uniqueId

Comment: user3667973: I have looked around and I think that is the only way to do this. Essentially, it appears that my JS code will have to loop through and find the record that got updated and then as @hasH mentioned, use splice to update the array. Hopefully, once I do that, the UI will automatically be updated by Angular. Jeetendra Chauhan, any other option that comes to your mind before I go down this path? Thanks!

Comment: Life would have been much much easier if you have chosen key value pair type data structure. Then updating would have been a matter of just array[key] = new_data;

Answer (score 9):

I am assuming that you can retrieve the index of corresponding data you want to update. 
So, you can try.

```
dataList.splice(index, 1);
dataList.splice(index, 0, newItem);
```

Comment: Thanks @user3667973 / HasH. I will give it a whirl but was curious to see if Angular offered any easier way of doing this. Will update this post with what I find.

Comment: What am I missing, I don't understand why dataList[index] = newItem is not the answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
$scope.setActive = function(user) {
  User.get({ id: user._id }, function(user){
      user.active = true;
      user.$update(function(user){
        angular.forEach($scope.users, function(u, i) {
          if (u._id === user._id ) {
            $scope.users[i] = user;
          }
        });
      });
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Angular view update automatically when its model change so no need to do something extra, just update your model in controller for ex-

```
$scope.data = ajaxdata // data you received from server
```

and in your view

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

for updating your data you should have some unique key-value pair(u_id in this case) like below code example

```
$scope.items = [{
    "status": "New",
    "priority_summary": "High",
    "u_id" : 1
}, {
    "status": "New",
    "priority_summary": "High",
    "u_id" : 2
}, {
    "status": "New",
    "priority_summary": "High",
    "u_id" : 3
}, {
    "status": "New",
    "priority_summary": "High",
    "u_id" : 4
}];
```

Comment: Are you saying that I should re-bind the data to the $scope instead of trying to find the item in the array and updating its attribute?

Comment: angular provide 2-way data binding, so when you update your model, your view will render with new data.

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining this correctly. My Angular model has 50 items and the 35th changed external to the web page. At this point, I need to find the 35th item and update it. My question is to figure out how I can find the 35th item and update it. Typical Angular methods such as Push, Pop etc. are inserts, not updates. Does that clarify? Thanks.

Comment: can you post the structure of array of objects/ object of objects whichever you are using ?

Comment: @DevIntern your server return only updated data or all data? and which method you are using to retrieve data

Comment: @JeetendraChauhan: My server returns updated data only. I am using a custom method implemented on the server side, and I call it as part of the controller initialization. I will add some code to the question so that it is clearer. Thanks!

Comment: @hasH: I will add a sample of the array structure. Thanks!