# Filter array of objects remove duplicates by property [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have `$scope.notys`  array  in my controller and `ng-repeat`:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in notys" class="item js-item">
...
```

From my controller I push data into array like this:

`$scope.notys.push(data);`

Every `data` have uniques id property `data.id`

Question is how can I update/replace object where property is same with last `data.id` which comes from ajax?

So I need to do something like this:

1. Get `data` from ajax
2. Now have `data.id` from ajax I need to check if in `$scope.notys` exists object with same `data.id`
3. If exists then replace it with last data, if not then just `push` data

Comment: My guess is that you'd have to do this manually: before you push the new data object, check if it already exists in your list. If it does: Update the entry, if it doesn't: Push the new data.

Comment: How to check if already exists?

Comment: You might want to take look at a library like underscore that will help you do these kind of array manupulations

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, this has been addressed here before. Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881580/how-do-you-update-an-existing-item-in-an-angular-array-that-has-changed-externa

Comment: Try library [js-data](http://www.js-data.io/) ... will handle all of it for you with very simple api and lots of robust  features

Comment: An object (hash) keyed on data.id might be a better datastructure than an array for this problem

Comment: Also, if you use `track by`, there may be little performance difference to simply overwriting the whole `notys` array each time

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your array into key-value pairs (id-index) using [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). If the id exists as a key, then you easily have the index. You can then [`array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) using that index to splice off the old and put in the new.

```js
var arr = [{id:1, value:'foo'},{id:2, value:'bar'}]
var idIndexMap = arr.reduce(function(carry, item){
  carry[item.id] = item.value;
  return carry;
}, {});

var newItem = {id:1, value: 'baz'};
var indexOfExisting = idIndexMap[newItem.id];

if(indexOfExisting !== undefined) arr.splice(indexOfExisting, 1, newItem);

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: Could you provide me some example how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found this simple solution:

```
angular.forEach($scope.notys, function (value, key) {
    if(value.id === data.id) $scope.notys.splice(key,1);
});
$scope.notys.push(data);
```

First I remove element if element exists with same id and then push new element.